# Geofire cocoapods error running pod install

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, dart, geofire

Once i add flutter geofire to my project it wouldn't run, for some reasons.
I have tried alot of stuffs the one that happens to work is:

pod init ,
pod install
this works but then after my google maps stops working and flutter for some reasons cannot import googlemaps in the AppDelegate file.
Here is the error :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `connectivity` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_database` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`
    firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_geofire` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_geofire/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `geolocator` from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_maps_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_a_d_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/4.2.0/GoogleMaps.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_7_9.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/7/9/Reachability/3.2/Reachability.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_auth":
      In Podfile:
        firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)

    Specs satisfying the `firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

I have done some research and I deleted my pod lock folder and also tried updating my cocoa pods by opening it in my terminal and running pod install --repo-update,
But it wouldn't still update and shows this error below:

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro ios % pod install --repo-update
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_auth":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
user@users-MacBook-Pro ios %
```

here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: padi_driver
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  firebase_database: ^6.1.0
  connectivity: ^3.0.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.1
  outline_material_icons: ^0.1.1
  geolocator: ^7.0.1
  http: ^0.13.1
  provider: ^5.0.0
  flutter_polyline_points: ^0.2.6
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
  animated_text_kit: ^4.0.0
 # flutter_geofire: ^2.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  assets:
    - images/


  fonts:
    - family: Brand-Bold
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/bolt-semibold.ttf

    - family: Brand-Regular
      fonts:
      - asset: fonts/bolt-regular.ttf

  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Yeah pls i need assistance i have spent a lot of time on this.
Thanks in advance :]

Comment: Hello community can i get some kind of an assistance with this?

Comment: You have to look up the errors on Stack Overflow and google. E.g. you got this error: “Specs satisfying the `firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform. ”

Comment: which 1. Tells specifically what the issue is and its resolution i.e. go see the link and see how you can specify a minimum deployment version. You might need to have both your project and Podfile use same minimum deployment version